# Extracting Data from Gmail Message using GAS

Tags: regex, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I've been working to automatically pull data from an automated Gmail message.  There are multiple daily emails that come through with the same label, so ideally I would like to loop through each email, and extract some of the data.  I've set it up to use a few regex to grab the data, and it works for the first email.  However, it won't loop correctly to find the next email with the label.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
function parseEmailMessages (start) {
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Bounce");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var tmp = [];
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
var bodies = [];

for (var i =0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var bodies = [];
   for(k in threads[i].getMessages()) {
   bodies.push(threads[i].getMessages()[i].getPlainBody());


    var content = bodies.toString();
    if (content) {
        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*First Name\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var firstname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*Last Name\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var lastname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No Lastname';

        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*Customer ID\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var customerID = (tmp) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No CustomerID';

        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*Invoice\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var invoice = (tmp) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No Invoice';

        sheet.appendRow([firstname, lastname, customerID, invoice]);
        Logger.log([firstname,lastname, customerID, invoice]);
      } 

       }


}

};
```

It loops through correctly the first time, and then gives me an error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getPlainBody" of undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that error because you should use k variable in the for loop to get each message of that label. Check this line below:

```
threads[i].getMessages()[k].getPlainBody()
```

Tried changing this line in the for loop and its working for me.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for the note, it did get rid of the error.  However, the loop is not finding the second email with that label.  In my inbox, I have two emails with the label "Bounce".  However, my spreadsheet is populating two rows of the same data.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After simplifying my code, I was able to get the script to loop correctly through my emails.  This is the code that worked for me:

```
function processInboxToSheet() {

// Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!

//var start = 0;
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Bounce");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var result = [];
var newLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Done");
var oldLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Bounce");


for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

  var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();

  // implement your own parsing rule inside
 if (content) {
    var tmp;
    tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*First Name\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var firstname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*Last Name\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var lastname = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No Lastname';

        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*Customer ID\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var customerID = (tmp) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No CustomerID';

        tmp = content.match(/[\n\r].*Invoice\s*:\s*([^\n\r]*)/);
        var invoice = (tmp) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No Invoice';

        sheet.appendRow([firstname, lastname, customerID, invoice]);
      } 

    Utilities.sleep(500);
    threads[i].addLabel(newLabel).removeLabel(oldLabel).refresh();
  }
};
```